# button with localstorage in order to increase speed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few buttons that increase the speed of an automatic mouse, every button increase a little bit the speed. I have these buttons because I tried to create only a button to increase gradually the speed and other that reduce it.

These are the funtions that I have now:

```
    function aumentar() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 2000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '2000')
}

function aumentar_mas() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '1000')
}

function aumentar_mas_mas() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 500);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '500')
}
```

I would like a function that increase for example 500 every time and other with the opposite. 
I tried something like that:

```
n = 3000;
function mas() {
n = n - 500;
t = setInterval(clickbutton,n);
localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n')
```

but it is not working fine. Any suggest?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that localStorage stores strings but interval durations need to be numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "clearInterval" to clearTimeout :) Also, remember to call `parseInt()` after getting numbers from local storage.

```js
var t; //define T here to be accessible outside 1 function call

function clickbutton(){
    console.log('clickbutton called')
}

function aumentar() {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 2000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '2000')
}

function aumentar_mas() {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '1000')
}

function aumentar_mas_mas() {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 500);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '500')
}

n = 3000;
function mas() {
    n = n - 500;
    t = setInterval(clickbutton,n);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', n)
}

mas()
```

```html
<button onclick="aumentar()">2000</button>
<button onclick="aumentar_mas()">1000</button>
<button onclick="aumentar_mas_mas()">500</button>
```

Comment: thank u so much! u were really useful! Now, its working! :)